# Python Win32COM unable to provide parameter when default value is set on server

Tags: python, com, win32com

I have a third party .net application with some methods with default parameters. While using python win32com I am able to call most methods, but some methods with default parameters seem to be inferred by `Dispatch` to be accessed like a member rather than a method.

Server Side pseudocode:

```
namespace MyApp.Application
{
  public class ComClass {
    public object doSomethingResult { get; set; }

    private void doSomethingAsync() {
        this.doSomethingResult = { name: "test", value: 1 };
    }

    private object doSomethingSync() {
        object result = {name: "test", value: 2};

        return result;
    }

    public object doSomething(bool sync = true) {
        if (sync) {
            return doSomethingSync();
        } else {
            doSomethingAsync();
        }
    }

    public object doSomethingElse(String input) {
        return {name: input, value: 3};
    }
  }
}
```

Client side:

```
import win32com.client
client = win32com.client.Dispatch('MyApp.Application.ComClass')

res = client.doSomething
res.name # test

res = client.doSomething(False) # TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

res = client.doSomethingElse('battle')
res.name # battle
```

I've tried many different things like using `GenCache`, `dynamic.Dispatch`, `dynamic.DumbDispatch`, etc. Though I'm obviously missing something here.

Comment: Does `client.doSomething(True)` work on the client side? What happens if you call the class from VBA?

Comment: Try doSomething(0)